Series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(x)} {n!}$ seems to equal $f(x+1)$ (in many cases)?
A series of the form $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(x)} {n!} $$ just piqued my interest. I tried to get an idea of it by graphing the resulting function in Desmos and the series seems to converge to the weird function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(x)} {n!} = f(x+1)$ for every differentiable function that doesn't tend to infinity for any finite value.
The obvious questions follow: Does this work for any on any function of the previously mentioned type (I think the name for that is locally bounded, correct me if I'm wrong) and how would one prove it? If the first question is true, why doesn't this hold true for functions that are not of the mentioned type (especially non differentiable functions for a finite amount of inputs like $f(x)=|x|$)?
My skills as a tenth grade student (in Germany) are sadly not advanced enough to deal with these questions myself, though I am very interested in the way that this could be solved. It is kind of similar to a Taylor Series, but I wouldn't know how to start approaching this kind of problem. It doesn't even seem obvious that this series $S: C^{\infty}({\mathbb{R}}) \rightarrow C^{\infty}({\mathbb{R}})$ actually maps to $C^{\infty}({\mathbb{R}})$, as the set $C^{\infty}({\mathbb{R}})$ would need to be sequentially compact, right? Anyway, I am quite confused on this. Any help or guidance would be very appreciated!

It's not similar to the Taylor Series, it is the Taylor Series $f(x+h) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)$ for $h=1$.

@Ramashalanka : There is no analog of $h = (x-c)$ in his version.

You may like to read about the shift operator.  Lagrange's shift operator, $T^1$ is literally the series you write.

"Locally bounded" is not what you're looking for; neither is "differentiable". What we want is analytic (and more strongly, analytic at every point with radius of convergence always greater than one)

In operational calculus, we sometimes write $T:=e^D$ where $T$ is the translation operator (takes a $C^\infty$ function $f$ and maps it to $Tf:x\mapsto f(x+1)$) and $D$ is the derivative $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$. Your question (and @Ramashalanka's comment) is exactly the reason why!

If $f$ is "analytic," and this series converges, then yes, you are correct.

Most of the usual functions we know well are analytic. Trig functoons, exponential functions, rational functions, and any composition of such functions.

Another surprising series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} x^n$

@EricTowers There certainly is an analog of $h$ and it's just as my comment says.

@Ramashalanka : False.  There is no analog of $h^n$ in OP's series.

@Ramashalanka : Alternatively, what is the center of OP's series?  Where is the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of the difference between that center and some other $x$?  The "center" is $x$, so your $h$ is zero in OP's series.

@EricTowers The analog of $h^n$ is $1^n=1$ since $h=1$. The center of the OP's series is $x$. The $n^\mathrm{th}$ power of the difference between that center and some other $x$, $(x+1)$ is $1$, not zero. Write $f(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(y-c)^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(c)$, $y-c=h=1$, $c=x$, $y=c+h=x+h=x+1$.

@Ramashalanka : At last!  Your comments, taken together, finally comprise the Answer you should have written in the first place.
